# Classic ASP - using one connection for many queries?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, connection-pooling

Consider a classic ASP site running on IIS6 with a dedicated SQL Server 2008 backend...

#### Scenario 1:

Open Connection
Do 15 queries, updates etc all through the ASP-page
Close Connection

#### Scenario 2:

For each query, update etc, open and close the connection

---

With connection pooling, my money would be on scenario 2 being the most effective and scalable.

Would I be correct in that assumption?

### Edit: More information

This is database operations spread over a lot of asp-code in separate functions, doing separate things etc. It is not 15 queries done in rapid succession. Think a big site with many functions, includes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are considering sharing a connection object across complex code held in various functions in various includes.

In such a scenario this would be a bad idea.  It becomes difficult to guarantee the correct state and settings on the connection if other code may have seen the need to modify them.  Also you may at times have code that fetches a firehose recordset and hasn't finished processing when another piece of code is invoked that also needs a connection.  In such a case you could not share a connection.

Having each atomic chunk of code acquire its own connection would be better.  The connection would be in a clean known state.  Multiple connections when necessary can operate in parrallel.  As others have pointed out the cost of connection creation is almost entirely mitigated by the underlying connection pooling.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, ASP pages are synchronous.  So why not open a connection once per page load, and close it once per page load?  All other opens/closes seem to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

in your Scenario 2, there is a round-trip between your application and SQLServer for executing each query which consumes your server's resources and time of total executions will raise.
but in Scenario 1, there is only one round-trip and also SQLServer will run all of the queries in just one time. so it is faster and less resource-consuming

**EDIT:** well, I thought you mean multiple queries in one time..
so, with connection pooling enabled, there is exactly no problem in closing connection after each transaction. so go with Scenario 2

Comment: Heinzi>> Spot on. This is database operations spread over a lot of asp-code in seperate functions, doing seperate things etc. I will try to improve my question.

Comment: okay, I got the question in wrong way, now with your edit, question is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to open the connection once, read all your data and close the connection as soon as possible. AFTER you've closed the connection, you can do what you like with the data you retrieved. In this scenario, you don't open too many connections and you don't open the connection for too long.

Even though your code has database calls in several places, the overhead of creating the connection will make things worse than waiting - unless you're saying your page takes many seconds to create on the server side? Usually, even without controlled data access and with many functions, your page should be well under a second to generate on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default connection pool is about 20 connections but SQLServer can handle alot more. Getting a connection from the server takes the longest time (assuming you are not doing anything daft with your commands) so I see nothing wrong with getting a connection per page and killing it if used afterwards.

For scalability you could run into problems where your connection pool gets too busy and time outs while your script waits for a connection to be come available while your DB is sat there with a 100 spare connections but no one using them.

Create and kill on the same page gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance point of view there is no notable difference. ADODB connection pooling manages the actual connections with the db. Adodb.connection .open and .close are just a façade to the connection pool. Instantiating either 1 or 15 adodb.connection objects doesn't really matter performance wise. Before we where using transactions we used the connection string in combination with adodb.command (.activeConnection) and never opened or closed connections explicitly.

Reasons to explicitly keep reference to a adodb.connection are transactions or connection-based functions like mysql last_inserted_id(). In these cases you must be absolutely certain that you are getting the same connection for every query.